# Make each word of a sentence in a UILabel tappable

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm displaying some text in a UILabel. How can I make each word of the sentence selectable by the user?

The sentence has a random length, so the number of lines and the lengths of the words vary.

Comment: Maybe you can use `addGestureRecognizer` for the `textView` you are using to display the sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cleanest way to do this will be to convert the string of your text view into an `NSAttributedString`.

You could add link attributes to each word one at a time. Do a search on "clickable text" and you should find some examples.

Note that you could also build your clickable words as an rtf in TextEdit, save the rtf file into your bundle, and load the attributed string for the text view by reading the RTF file from the bundle. (Take a look at the docs for NSAttributedString, specifically the method
`initWithURL:options:documentAttributes:error:` and the document type attribute `NSRTFDTextDocumentType`

### EDIT:

I see from the edit to your question that you want to make the text selectable, not tappable. I thought you wanted clickable links. The above will give you that.

The text of a label can't be selectable. You will need to use a text view or text field for that, and set the selectable flag.